# Creating multiple records of the same type in Redux-Persist

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit, redux-persist

I'm building an online store using React with Redux-Persist. I have an idea to store the user's cart in local storage, creating a separate entry in the local storage for each user (I think it would be more convenient). However, I'm not sure how to switch Redux-Persist to the right setup after changing the user. Currently, I have a general entry with the key 'basket'. I'd like to have 'basket/userId' for each user.

Here's my code:

```
// store.ts

import { combineReducers, configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { FLUSH, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER, REHYDRATE, persistReducer, persistStore } from "redux-persist";
import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage";
import basketSlice from './slices/basket/basket.slice';
import categoriesSlice from "./slices/category.slice";
import ordersSlice from './slices/orders.slice';
import userSlice from "./slices/user/user.slice";

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  basket: basketSlice,
  orders: ordersSlice,
  categories: categoriesSlice,
  user: userSlice
});

const persistConfig = {
  key: `basket`, // I want "basket/userId" for each user
  storage,
  whitelist: ['basket'],
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => {
    return getDefaultMiddleware({
      serializableCheck: {
        ignoredActions: [FLUSH, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER, REHYDRATE],
      },
    });
  },
});

export const persistor = persistStore(store);

export type RootType = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>;
```

```
// user.slice.ts

import { getValueFromLocalStorage } from "@/functions/getValueFromLocalStorage";
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { checkAuth, auth, logout } from "./user.actions";
import { IInitialState } from "./user.interface";

const initialState: IInitialState = {
  user: getValueFromLocalStorage('user'),
  isLoading: false
}
 
const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'user',
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(auth.pending, (state) => {
      state.isLoading = true;
    })
    
    .addCase(auth.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      state.isLoading = false;
      state.user = action.payload.user;
    })
      
    .addCase(auth.rejected, (state) => {
      state.isLoading = false;
      state.user = null;
    })

    .addCase(logout.fulfilled, (state) => {
      state.isLoading = false;
      state.user = null;
    })

    .addCase(checkAuth.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      state.user = action.payload.user;
    })
  }
});

export default userSlice.reducer;




// user.actions.ts

import { errorCatch } from '@/api/api.helper';
import { AuthType } from '@/components/screens/Auth/auth.types';
import { removeFromStorage } from '@/services/auth/auth.helper';
import AuthService from '@/services/auth/auth.service';
import { createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { IAuthResponse, IEmailPassword } from './user.interface';

export const auth = createAsyncThunk<
  IAuthResponse,
  { type: AuthType; data: IEmailPassword }
>(`auth`, async ({ type, data }, thunkApi) => {
  try {
    const response = await AuthService.main(type, data);
    return response;
  } catch (error) {
    return thunkApi.rejectWithValue(error);
  }
});

export const logout = createAsyncThunk('auth/logout', async () =>
  removeFromStorage()
);

export const checkAuth = createAsyncThunk<IAuthResponse>(
  'auth/check-auth',
  async (_, thunkApi) => {
    try {
      const response = await AuthService.getNewTokens();
      return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
      if (errorCatch(error) === 'jwt expired') thunkApi.dispatch(logout());

      return thunkApi.rejectWithValue(error);
    }
  }
);
```

```
// App.tsx

import { Toaster } from '@/components/ui/toaster';
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from '@tanstack/react-query';
import { ReactQueryDevtools } from '@tanstack/react-query-devtools';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react';
import Paths from './components/routes/Routes';
import { persistor, store } from './store/store';

const queryClient = new QueryClient({
  defaultOptions: {
    queries: {
      refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
    },
  },
});

function App() {
  return (
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
          <Paths />
          <Toaster />
        </PersistGate>
        <ReactQueryDevtools initialIsOpen={false} />
      </Provider>
    </QueryClientProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
// basketSlice.ts

import { IBasketItem } from "@/interfaces/basket.interface";
import { createSlice, PayloadAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { IBasketSlice } from "./basket.types";

const initialState: IBasketSlice = {
  products: null
};
 
const basketSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'basket',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addProductToBasket(state, action: PayloadAction<IBasketItem>) {
      if (state.products) state.products.push(action.payload);
      else state.products = [action.payload];
    },
    deleteProductFromBasket(state, action: PayloadAction<number>) {
      if (!state.products) return;
      state.products = state.products.filter(product => product.id !== action.payload);
    },
  }
});

export const basketActions = basketSlice.actions;
export default basketSlice.reducer;
```

P.S.

1. My user data is stored in user.slice.
2. According to my plan, 'basketItem' will only store the item ID and its quantity
3. If creating a separate entry for each user turns out to be too complex, please advise on how to store all items in a single local storage entry but filter out unnecessary ones on the client side.

Comment: A bit punny, but you are putting the cart before the horse. You would likely need to read from the Redux store to know the user id that could be used to read the correct persisted state to create the Redux store. Why do you want to store each user's cart locally where any other user could access/view it? You can't save the cart server-side and fetch it for only the specific user? You may be able to do this with a little more hands-on approach with the localStorage *after* you have an authenticated user. Is this an approach you are interested in?

Comment: I just wanted to try out redux-persist. As for allowing any user access to items - I don't see anything wrong with that (if I understood you correctly). Regarding the user: what I meant was that when a user logs into another account, it will be necessary to change the key in persistConfig in order to store their data in a new local storage entry.

Comment: If it is the same user signing into different accounts then I agree that there's likely no security issue. I understood well enough you are asking how to use a dynamic persist key. The issue here though is that the key is dependent on a value that it is stored in the store it is persisting. This is why I suggested the hands-on approach. Redux-persist is meant to be used with static keys that are determinant prior to creating the store instance.

Comment: @DrewReese Got your point, thank you. I'm just following a tutorial where the author stores the cart data in local storage but doesn't address the situation I described, hence these questions.

Comment: No worries at all. Are you interested in a suggested solution to accomplish this? Or are you moving along in the tutorial? I don't want you to get bogged down if your intent is to just gain familiarity with the Redux-Persist technology.

Comment: Well, I understand perfectly how this could be done by creating a table in the database, fetching items through a service, etc. I was just curious if it's possible to achieve what I described in my question.

Comment: I've already understood how redux-persist works. It can be used for website themes, for example.

Comment: Possible, yes, I believe so. Possible using Redux-Persist, no, not really. I'm basically asking if the answer to your question that "No, you can't do exactly what you want to do with Redux-Persist" is sufficient, or if you still want a working solution for your goal.

Comment: Oops, sorry for my clumsy English, I must have misunderstood you. I'd like to see even a workaround. Perhaps, I might really like it and adopt it. But most likely, I'll rewrite the code for services, etc.

Comment: No worries at all, I'm happy to help. Can you [edit] to include your `basketSlice` code? Maybe include those `getValueFromLocalStorage` and `removeFromStorage` functions (*and any other helper utilities*) as well since I suspect they could be useful here?

Comment: @DrewReese Updated the question. basketSlice.ts isn't finished yet. I've only added the foundation there, from which I tested only the addition. Could you elaborate more on these utilities? I didn't quite understand you. You're talking about the option where I'm not using redux-persist, meaning I'll manually manage the local storage?

Comment: Yes, it looks like you have already some utility functions for working with localStorage, e.g. `import { getValueFromLocalStorage } from "@/functions/getValueFromLocalStorage";` and `import { removeFromStorage } from '@/services/auth/auth.helper';`. I wanted to see them in case they were important for working with storage in your app. They might not be necessary here though since I believe you can work with localStorage directly regardless.

Comment: These are utilities that are called after authorization (registration) and logging out. They add/remove tokens and user data to/from local storage, nothing interesting. As I understood from the last sentence, if I decide to keep local storage, I'll need to develop my own functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redux-Persist expects the storage key to be static. The problem you have is that you *could* use a dynamically computed key, but the key value you want/need is stored in the Redux store you are persisting. Since the user baskets are the only values being persisted I would suggest a more manual and localized persistence of the basket state where you can dynamically persist multiple baskets.

Add an `id` property to the `IBasketSlice` interface:

```js
interface IBasketSlice {
  id: string;
  products: Product[] | null;
}
```

Update the basket slice to respond to auth changes to set a local id for the current basket you want to interact with, and to persist/load the products array to/from localStorage:

```js
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { auth, checkAuth, logout } from '../path/to/user.actions.ts';

const initialState: IBasketSlice = {
  id: "",
  products: null,
};
 
const basketSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'basket',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addProductToBasket(state, action: PayloadAction<IBasketItem>) {
      if (state.products) {
        state.products.push(action.payload);
      } else {
        state.products = [action.payload];
      }

      if (state.id) {
        localStorage.setItem(
          `basket/${state.id}`,
          JSON.stringify(state.products)
        );
      }
    },
    deleteProductFromBasket(state, action: PayloadAction<number>) {
      if (!state.products) return;

      state.products = state.products.filter(
        product => product.id !== action.payload
      );

      if (state.id) {
        localStorage.setItem(
          `basket/${state.id}`,
          JSON.stringify(state.products)
        );
      }
    },
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    const resetBasket = (state) => {
      state.id ="";
      state.products = null;
    };

    const setBasket = (state, action) => {
      const { id } = action.payload.user;
      state.id = id;
      state.products = 
        JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(`basket/${id}`)) ?? [] as Product[];
    };

    builder
      .addCase(auth.fulfilled, setBasket)
      .addCase(checkAuth.fulfilled, setBasket)
      .addCase(auth.rejected, resetBasket)
      .addCase(logout.fulfilled, resetBasket);
  }
});
```

I haven't tested this in a running sandbox or anything so please do double-check the Typescript typings/syntax/etc since I'm only using a plain text editor here.